# Prefer .NET Standard 2.0 library reference over .NET 4.5.1 from a .NET 4.7.2 project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, morelinq

I have an old-style C# WPF project file. It is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project. I want to reference a NuGet library that has builds for .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.5.1. An example of this would be [morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/3.0.0).

As I understand it, .NET Framework 4.7.2 fully implements the .NET Standard 2.0 API. Therefore I would like my project to reference the .NET Standard 2.0 build in the NuGet package instead of the .NET Framework 4.5.1 build. The benefit of this would be that the .NET Standard 2.0 version of `morelinq` does not have additional dependencies, e.g. on `System.ValueTuple`.

However, when I add the NuGet package, it defaults to referencing the .NET Framework 4.5.1 build and hence, includes its additional dependencies.

This is only one of a few such cases. So at the moment it seems, to me at least, that I'm references many unnecessary additional dependencies that could be avoided.

(My apologies if this is a duplicate. I did try searching first.)

Comment: *...does not have additional dependencies, e.g. on `System.ValueTuple`*. It does. However, it is prepackaged in the .NET Standard library.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ok, so that's a matter of phrasing. I would like to use the prepackaged versions, as .NET 4.7.2 is .NET Standard 2.0 compliant.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood what is meant by .NET 4.7.2 is .NET Standard 2.0 compliant.

Comment: Patrick's comment causes too much confusion, there is no such thing as a ".netstandard app".  The term only applies to libraries, dlls.  The app that uses the library, the exe, must always target a specific platform.  Otherwise easy to see when you create such an app in VS, no way to pick it.  You should *not* favor a .netstandard library in a desktop app when a desktop library is available.  The runtime hoochie-moochie that is required to forward types from the reference assembly to the runtime assembly is not for free.

Comment: Adding to Hans' comment, I think that "many unnecessary additional dependencies" is somewhat smoke and mirrors. If you use NuGet *at all* then the difference between "It depends on netstandard20" and "It depends on 20 small packages" is not a meaningful difference. I can see that the appearance of a single dependency feels tidier, but it's more appearance that reality

Comment: Ok, so this is the debate that led me here: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/348  . I just want to pull in a `System.ValueTuple` package in my net472 project. See the last comment. I understood from that that I *should* be targeting the netstandard20 build.